# How to setup Samba4 to enable NTFS encryption?

Tags: samba, encryption, encrypting-file-system, samba4

I'm currently giving the [sernet.de samba4 (rc1) appliance](ftp://ftp.sernet.de/pub/samba4AD/sernet-samba4-appliance/) a shot (running inside vmware player on Windows 7). Providing a share is no problem, but the client still can't choose to encrypt files. What settings do need to be changed in the simplest case? I'm not interested in using AD at the moment, unless necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm reasonably certain that Samba4 does not support hosting the Encrypting File System. None of the changelogs since Samba 3.0 mention it as a feature, and the Samba 3 page itself shows it as a feature they'd like to have since Microsoft released details about how it works; which is different than a feature they actually have.

Comment: I could swear I read somewhere that Samba4 supports it, but maybe I accidentally read to much into `Full NTFS semantics for sharing backends` from [the Samba4 Wiki](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba4)